# Trying to do SVR for Multi-outputs

Tags: python, svm, grid-search, gridsearchcv

Since SVR supports only a single output, I am trying to employ SVR on my model which has 6 inputs and 19 outputs using `MultiOutputRegressor`.

I am starting with hyper-parameter tuning. However, I am getting the error below. How can I modify my code to support `MultiOutputRegressor`?

```
from sklearn.svm import SVR
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV

svr = SVR()
svr_regr = MultiOutputRegressor(svr)

from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
kfold_splitter = KFold(n_splits=6, random_state = 0,shuffle=True)

#On each iteration, the algorithm will choose a difference combination of the features.
svr_random = RandomizedSearchCV(svr_regr,
                  param_distributions = {'kernel': ('linear','poly','rbf','sigmoid'),
                                         'C': [1,1.5,2,2.5,3,3.5,4,4.5,5,5.5,6,6.5,7,7.5,8,8.5,9,9.5,10],
                                         'degree': [3,8],
                                         'coef0': [0.01,0.1,0.5],
                                         'gamma': ('auto','scale')
                                         'tol': [1e-3, 1e-4, 1e-5, 1e-6]},
                  n_iter=100,
                  cv=kfold_splitter,
                  n_jobs=-1,
                  random_state=42,
                  scoring='r2') 
svr_random.fit(X_train, y_train)


print(svr_random.best_params_)
```

Error:

```
ValueError: Invalid parameter kernel for estimator MultiOutputRegressor(estimator=SVR()). Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()`.
```

**After getting the optimum parameters:**

```
SVR_model = svr_regr (kernel='rbf',C=10,
                      coef0=0.01,degree=3,
                      gamma='auto',tol=1e-6,random_state=42)
SVR_model.fit(X_train, y_train)
SVR_model_y_predict = SVR_model.predict((X_test))
SVR_model_y_predict
```

**Error after getting the optimum parameters:**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/mm/r4gnnwl948zclfyx12w803040000gn/T/ipykernel_96269/769104914.py in <module>
----> 1 SVR_model = svr_regr (estimator__kernel='rbf',estimator__C=10,
      2                       estimator__coef0=0.01,estimator__degree=3,
      3                       estimator__gamma='auto',estimator__tol=1e-6,random_state=42)
      4 
      5 

TypeError: 'MultiOutputRegressor' object is not callable
```

Comment: You probably mean `GridSearchCV` rather than `RandomizedSearchCV` as you have specified a grid of parameters rather than distributions.

Comment: @njp may you please advise on my other error since you've done this before and you're a reputable member? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73396919/error-while-doing-svr-for-multiple-outputs

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce a simple example of `MultiOutputRegressor` without using `GridSearchCV` (i.e. just the fit and predict methods), which seemed to work fine. The error message:

> Check the list of available parameters with estimator.get_params().keys()

suggests that the parameters that you are optimising in `GridSearchCV`, i.e. through `param_distributions`, don't match the parameters accepted by `MultiOutputRegressor`. Looking at the [API reference](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multioutput.MultiOutputRegressor.html), there are only a few parameters that `MultiOutputRegressor` takes, and the parameters you are trying to pass through to `SVR`, e.g. `C` and `tol` belong to the support vector machine estimator.

You may be able to pass through parameters to `SVR` via nested parameters similar to [how it's done in a pipeline](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/compose.html#nested-parameters).

Comment: Thank you for posting your answer. So I've obtained the optimum parameters, now I want to create the model based on them, I get another error though. I've updated the code.

Comment: If the parameters are optimized through `GridSearchCV` or similar, you can use the `best_estimator_` attribute of `GridSearchCV` after fitting (make sure `refit=True`).